# Probability of overlap with reshuffle

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I have a set $A_0$ with $n$ objects, and then $p$ random reshufflings $A_p$ of $A$. What is the probability, in terms of $n$ and $p$, that there is an index $i$ in $A$ such that $A_{0,i}=A_{1,i}=A_{2,i}\cdots =A_{p,i}$?

This came up in a computer science problem I'm dealing with, and probability really isn't my strong suit. I know that for each $A_p$, there are $n$ possibilities at index $i$. So, fixing $A_{0,i}$, the probability of $A_{1,i}$ being the same is $\frac1n$. Continuing, the probability that all of them at that index are the same is $\frac{1}{n^p}$. With $n$ objects, then, the probability that one of them fits this is $\frac{n}{n^p}=n^{1-p}$. Is this correct logic, or am I messing up my independence assumption somewhere?

Comment: Your "With $n$ objects, then, the probability that one of them fits this is $\frac{n}{n^p}=n^{1-p}$" is not correct.  Even if you assumed independence (wrong, but possibly not that wrong if $n$ is large) you would have $1-(1-n^{-p})^n$ that there is least one overlap

Comment: @Henry Right, of course - that makes sense. Do you know how to do it without the independence assumption, though?

Comment: If you don't assume that the reshufflings are independent, the problem isn't well-defined, since the result then depends on the joint probability distribution of the reshufflings (which you don't specify).